# Convert a Pandas dataframe with multiple rows into one row

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I need to convert a Pandas dataframe with multiple rows into one row.

Having the following dataframe.

```
X     Y    V
A     0    0.1
A     1    0.2
B     0    0.3
B     1    0.4
```

I'd like to convert the dataframe to the following format. `V_0` means "Value where `Y=0`". How to achieve this transformation?

```
X     V_0    V_1
A     0.1    0.2
B     0.3    0.4
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using [`pd.DataFrame.pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
res = df.pivot(index='X', columns='Y').add_prefix('V_')
res.columns = res.columns.droplevel(0)
res = res.reset_index()

print(res)

Y  X  V_0  V_1
0  A  0.1  0.2
1  B  0.3  0.4
```